# Does LLVM IR support (byte = 16bit)?

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

Wondering if LLVM supports bytes with a size of 16bit etc (not just 8bit)?
Is it possible to make a language that targets LLVM and supports this concept for custom 16bit FPGA-CPUs ?

From my understanding Clang doesn't support this while GCC can BUT does LLVM IR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In LLVM there is no specific concept of bytes, int, etc. All it supports is integers with arbitrary bit width (iN).

`1 <= N <= (2^23)-1`

https://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#integer-type

Suppose, in some language a byte = 16 bits, the language front-end should make sure it generates `i16` instead of `i8`. LLVM IR is designed to accommodate many different languages, that is the reason for this arbitrary integer bit widths.

> Is it possible to make a language that targets LLVM and supports this concept for custom 16bit FPGA-CPUs ?

Yes, I understood the term "16-bit FPGA-CPU" as a 16-bit soft processor. LLVM does natively support processors with various bit widths. To my understanding, it does not matter if it is a soft processor or not.

In LLVM IR at the top, we find something called data layout. The one below is X86_64 data layout. `n8:16:32:64` indicates the processor has native support for processing 64, 32, 16 and 8 bits, this means it is a 64-bit processor with backward compatibility.

```
target datalayout = "e-m:e-i64:64-f80:128-n8:16:32:64-S128"
```

Information about the rest of the field can found here.
https://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#langref-datalayout

Comment: Does that mean the IR also supports f16 for floating point hardware?

Comment: Floating point bit widths are not arbitrary, they follow IEEE 754 standard. Yes, LLVM supports f16 also. https://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#t-floating

Comment: For example HLSL supports 10bit floats for HDR. My thinking was you could make a language that targets LLVM IR and recognize f10 for uncommon hardware... but I guess in those cases you make a special type that your runtime understands as a special case instead.